# Need a Regular expression to remove a pattern/string

Tags: regex

I have the following text

> |1 Style Indented Normal + Courier New T201_LLR_001|2 Style Indented Normal + Courier New  Shall accept the three pointers.|3 Style Indented Normal + Courier New  SSC_01_SRS_0001

I need to convert this text to get three seperate output

> - T201_LLR_001
> - Shall accept the three pointers
> - SSC_01_SRS_0001

I used the following regular  `(\S+_LLR_\d+)(.+)\t(SSC_.+)*`

to get the following output

> - T201_LLR_001
> - |2 Style Indented Normal + Courier New    Shall accept the three pointers.|3 Style Indented Normal + Courier New
> - SSC_01_SRS_0001

But, I need to get rid of the text `|2 Style Indented Normal + Courier New" and "|3 Style Indented Normal + Courier New`

Is it possible in regular expression?
I dont know how to use `(?!TEXT)`.

Comment: What is exactly the pattern you have? To me it seems that your regex is tailored to this very example.

Comment: does the Shall accept text always start with a given pattern eg Shall accept :) ?

Comment: Please tell us (algorithmically) how `"Shall accept the three pointers"` was chosen so we are able to uniquely identify it in the string.

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: Thanks. The text given as input is a converted text from a MSWord table. where in T201_LLR_001 is in the first column, Shall accept the three pointers is in the second column and SSC_01_SRS_0001 in the third. The text in the second column will vary and wont start with shall always. The tool which I work will convert the word tables to a text format(and the text given is an example). That tool can only understand regular expressions(like any other editor) to process further. And I need to get rid of the style settings generated to get the exact text present

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions. I edited all yours and came up with the following

(\S+LLR\d+)\|\d.+\t(\w+\w+.+)\|\d.+\t(.+SRS\d+)*

which is almost near to what I want. But the style info starting with '|' (Eg : |2 Style Indented Normal + Courier New) need not be occuring twice.. I have to make it generic. If any suggestions please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who didn't notice it, I see there's a tab between the font and the string you want, this makes the problem rather easier.

This should give you what you want:

```
([^_\s]+_LLR_\d+)[^\t]*\t([^|]*)[^\t]*\t(SSC_.+)
```

**Explanation:**

I changed `\S` (not whitespace) to `[^_\s]` (not underscore or whitespace).

Then you consume `T201_LLR_001`.

Then you consume everything up to and including the next tab, which will be `|2 Style Indented Normal + Courier New`.

Then you consume everything up to the `|`, which will be `Shall accept the three pointers.` and store in a group by putting it in brackets.

Then you consume everything up to and including the next tab, which will be `|3 Style Indented Normal + Courier New`.

Then you consume `SSC_01_SRS_0001` and put it in a group.

[Java test](https://ideone.com/auU7Q4) correctly prints out:

```
T201_LLR_001
Shall accept the three pointers.
SSC_01_SRS_0001
```

Comment: Thanks. I also have one other issue. The '|2 Style Indented Normal + Courier New'(style info) may occur any number of times. Please can you help me in this?

Comment: If each of them are separated by tabs, you should be able to simply replace the first `[^\t]*\t` with `(?:[^\t]*\t)+`.

Comment: Thanks again. But this update didnt help for the input when the style info is like this" |1 Style Indented Normal + Courier New T201_LLR_001|2 Style Indented Normal + Courier New Text1 here.|2 Style Indented Normal + Courier New |2 Style Indented Normal + Courier New Text2 here.|2 Style Indented Normal + Courier New |3 Style Indented Normal + Courier New SSC_01_SRS_0001 " here we have style info available in between also. Please help

Comment: If there can be multiple style info's **before** the second string you want, you should replace the **first** `[^\t]*\t` with `(?:[^\t]*\t)+`. However, if these are **after**, you're supposed to replace the **second** ([test](https://ideone.com/ngiskJ)). If there can be multiple both before and after, you'll probably need to specify exactly how much on at least one side.

Answer (score 0):

Use another group to capture `|2 Style Indented Normal + Courier New` and `|3 Style Indented Normal + Courier New`. You can even use the non-capturing group (?:) for that, if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (.NET):

```
(?<=\|\d \w* \w* \w* \+ [a-z-A-Z0-9 ]*\t)[\w ]*
```

or this one:

```
(?<=\|\d [a-zA-Z+ ]*\t)[\w ]*
```